# How do I perform a function with side-effects over a vector?

Tags: clojurescript

The say-hello-to-first-person works fine, why doesn't say-hello-to-everyone?

```
(defpartial greeting [name]
  [:p.alert "Hello " name ", how are you?"])

(defn say-hello [name]
  (append $content (greeting name)))

(defn say-hello-to-first-person [names]
  (say-hello (first names)))

(defn say-hello-to-everyone [names]
  (map say-hello names))

(say-hello-to-first-person ["Chris" "Tom" "Jim" "Rocky"])
(say-hello-to-everyone ["Chris" "Tom" "Jim" "Rocky"])
```

Comment: see `doall` and `dorun` functions. Also `doseq` may be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`doseq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq), Clojure's "foreach":

```
(doseq [name names]
  (say-hello name))
```

`map` doesn't work because it produces a lazy sequence: Until you actually access the items in the sequence (which you don't here), none of them will be evaluated, and side effects won't occur.

Another option is to force evaluation by wrapping [`dorun`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/dorun) around the `map`. Thinking about why this works may help your understanding (although `doseq` is the idiomatic approach here).

Answer (score 2):

As @edbond says in his comment, map fn don't evaluate until necessary moment because map fn returns a lazy seq.

This is the doc of [map](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map) fn
    Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to the
    set of first items of each coll, followed by applying f to the set
    of second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is
    exhausted. Any remaining items in other colls are ignored. Function
    f should accept number-of-colls arguments.

If you need to be sure that the values are evaluate in one specific part of your code you can use [doall](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doall) or [dorun](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/dorun)

Comment: or (last (map side-effect-fn! -- will cause the lazy-seq to be realized, although this is not deemed good practice as it doesn't explain itself, in fact I don't even know why I'm bothering to say this ;-)